# How to add brackets to only specific ordered lists?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'd like to have an ordered list with a closing bracket after each decimal like so:

1.) Item 1
2.) Item 2
3.) Item 3

My problem is that any code I can find changes all lists in a document, but I'd like to have the brackets only for specific lists.
I tried to create a class, but apparently "ol" doesn't accept "classes", or does it?.

Here's the code I have so far, which results in every list receiving brackets:

```
<style>
ol > li::marker {
content:counter(list-item) ") ";
}
</style>

<ol>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<ol>
```

Comment: It does support classes, Id. You need to be specific in your selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ol` certainly supports classes, your implementation must be incorrect somewhere.

```css
ol.braces>li::marker {
  content: counter(list-item) ".) ";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>

<ol class="braces">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: You were absolutely correct. I did this: `ol > li::marker .brackets {...}`, which doesn't work.

Thanks for the solution!